# Interactive Dashboard Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, slice, powerbi-desktop, interactive

Hello i wanna create interactive dashboard using Power BI, that when i click some category on the graph, the other graph will be interactive. But i wanna create interactive dashboard that when i click the category on the graph the other value that doesnt have any relation will be not showing on the graph, can you help me with that guys? Thankyou

[image: This is the image]

My expetation is when i click some category, only show value that have relation to the clicked category ?

Answer (score 1):

try: format panel after selecting the visual > edit interactions > with on % contribuitions visual selected, apply filter (the icon as below) on the MTD visual, see if is the behaviour expected by you.

[image: filter visual icon]